# Adjusting signal voltage range for ADC

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, adc, voltage-measurement, level-shifting

Can anyone please help me design a system using an LM324 op-amp to amplify a small voltage signal (from -20 mV to 31.1 mV) to a larger voltage range (0 to 5 V) so that it can be read by an Arduino's analog input?

Comment: Have you read through the LM324 datasheet?  There are a fair number of example circuits and design parameters there that you could start with. - https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf

Comment: This Q/A forum is not a place where someone will draw up a schematic from your requirements. Rather it is a place to receive help on specific electronic design issues and to receive help in the understanding of such. To receive help you also need to show some effort on your part. For example consider editing your question to include your own preliminary circuit design. Then ask for help on a design step where you seem to be stuck, or ask a specific question about the design that you may not fully understand. Without some of the above changes your question could potentially be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The LM324 cannot produce +5V at its output with a supply of +5V, a limitation which is described on page  of the [LM324 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf), under "Output Voltage Swing". Note also that despite its claim to "operate down to ground", it is also unable to output closer than 20mV or so from its negative supply. Personally, I would never ask this device for lower than \$V_{EE}+50mV\$ out.

A realistic solution, then, using the LM324 powered from +5V, would account for the device's inability to guarantee more than +3V output, or under +50mV. If you require a true +5V output, you must apply +7V or more to the op-amp's positive supply pin, and if you wish for the output to get right down to 0V, then you must power its negative rail from -50mV or lower. You could obtain the full range 0V to +5V out, by using ±12V supplies, for example, but then you must remember to protect the ADC from signals outside the 0V...+5V range, which would now be possible.

A better solution would employ a rail-to-rail device, like the [TLC2272](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2272a.pdf?ts=1684471022879), which you can power from 0V and +5V, and still be able to produce an output very close to +5V and 0V, within a few tens of millivolts or so.

The solution I provide here, assuming you are forced to use the LM324 (or any op-amp with a significant maximum or minimum output voltage constraint) is to simply produce an output within the range possible using that device. You can always compensate for these adjustments in software.

---

The output you intend to produce then is +50mV...+3V, corresponding to an input -20mV...+31mV, from an op-amp powered with 0V and +5V.

You require a gain of \$\frac{(+3V)-(50mV)}{(+31mV)-(-20mV)}=58\$

The output should be +50mV when the input is -20mV, and output should be +3V when the input is +31mV.

This gives you the relationship:

$$ V_{OUT} = 58 \times V_{IN} + 1.21V $$

or:

$$ V_{OUT} = 58 \times (V_{IN} +20.9mV) $$

The distinction between these two representations is important. In the former, an offset of +1.21V is applied *after* the input signal has been multiplied by 58. In the latter, the offset of 20.9mV is applied *prior* to amplification.

In both cases, this offset must be derived somehow from whatever power supplies you have available, but I'm sure you understand that if you apply the offset prior to amplification, any error in that offset will appear 58 times greater by the time it reaches your ADC. This means that any fluctuation in your power supply, such as ripple from the regulator, will be of major concern.

You may therefore either produce an offset using a *precision* voltage source, applied prior to amplification, or amplify first, and then apply an offset of much lower required precision in a second stage.

With no negative supply available, you are forced to introduce the offset *prior* to amplification, since the op-amp input potentials are also bounded by the power supplies. If you had a -5V supply, for instance, this constraint would go away, and you could very easily amplify \$58 \times V_{IN}\$ and *then* offset, with two op-amps, with no real need for a precision voltage source.

I have to assume you want precision, and since you haven't specified what power supplies are available I have to assume also that all we have is a +5V source. This means offset first (to obtain a signal we *can* work with, between 0V and +5V) and amplify after:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq5lR6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{OUT}\$ vs. \$V_{IN}\$:

[image]

The TL431 is a precision voltage source, producing exactly 2.5V (although you could configure it to produce any voltage from 2.5V and up). It is used together with the potential divider formed by R1 and R2 to offset the input signal by about 20mV. That signal is then amplified by the non-inverting amplifier formed by OA1, R4 and R5.

This design doesn't account for any input offset voltage of the op-amp itself, which would also be multiplied by 58. You can change R2 to modify the offset somewhat to compensate for the op-amp's own imperfection in this respect.

---

If you *do* have a negative supply, of say −5V, you could use the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUel7u.png)</sup>

R3 and R4 apply the offset *after* amplification, and so we can dispense with the precision voltage source. It requires higher gain, though, to compensate for the attenuation due to R3 and R4.

Those two resistors will also limit output current, so if your ADC has input protection diodes, you can probably connect OUT directly to it, and let those diodes clamp the ADC input potential to a safe range, in case of \$V_{IN}\$ exceeding the expected limits.

Comment: +1, very thorough answer. I'm glad I didn't have a punt at answering it!